# How to revert back to old package style in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My Android Studio Version is 3.5.3

Following is an project structure

[image: Old Package Style]

and following is another new project's structure

[image: New Package Style]

Is there any way, can i convert new package style to old one? 
Maybe some setting.

Comment: Please use tag as android_studio, as it is more of a IDE thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Setting icon from the left menu and check the second option "Compact Middle Packages" and you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: `Compact Middle Packages` is different than `Flattern Packages`. I think you are looking for Flattern Packages.

Answer (score 1):

Check this image has ticked on `Flattern Packages`, Just Untick that option.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, since my packages are already Compact, it is showing option of `Flatten Packages` , I clicked it and it reverted back as I wanted. Thank you for your answer and Editing my qustion

Answer (score 0):

[image]

make sure you have selected project in dropdown and also try other option as per your need..